# I am getting error "Sorry! The Application Android_Name(process com.pckge) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." Force Close?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing this code and getting error:

> "Sorry! The Application
>   Android_Name(process com.pckge) has
>   stopped unexpectedly. Please try
>   again. Force Close"

What's the mistake?

```
package com.pckge;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Date;

public class Now extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
       btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            updateTime();
        setContentView(btn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        updateTime();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void updateTime() {
        btn.setText(new Date().toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Check your error log (under debug in eclipse) what kind of error you're getting and paste that here

Answer (score 6):

Your line

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

is called when 'btn' isn't yet initialized. It's NULL, so you can't call a member of it. Assign a real button to it first.

(be aware that  `Button btn;` only sets the type)

quoting @jems from the comment below as I agree with it:
Adding the line `btn = new Button(this)` right after super.onCreate should fix the problem, but it might be better to define your layout in xml instead

Comment: This is correct. Adding the line btn = new Button(this)  right after super.onCreate should fix the problem, but it might be better to define your layout in xml instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your button.
Im assuming you've created the button in XML and set android:name="buttonID".

Button btn;
btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonID);